# Can't find any users after login with q-municate

Tags: quickblox, q-municate

I cloned q-municate, went through the q-municate tutorial for Android, build with Android Studio, installed on 2 test devices, logged in both with Facebook (had to setup 2nd user as tester in Facebook dev).

I can't find the other user (in my own app). Quickblox dashboard shows users.

To research Quickblox, I initially downloaded original "q-municate" app from the Google playstore. I installed it on 2 phones, and logged in with phone (twitter digits) and Facebook. It was hard finding someone there too. But once connected, I was able to send messages back and forth. It didn't work great, but I'm guessing with the free tier that Quickblox has for their sample app, there is a limit to msgs and notifications.